# Obj C: Grouping strings into NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSArray that contains a bunch of strings.  Each string lists a parent and child type, such as:

```
Tool: Saw
Fruit: Apple
Fruit: Orange
Tree: Maple
Fruit: Banana
Tree: Oak
Tool: Hammer
Tree: Cedar
```

My final structure that I need to put them into is (sorted parents and children):

```
Fruit:
  - Apple
  - Banana
  - Orange
Tool:
  - Hammer
  - Saw
Tree:
  - Cedar
  - Maple
  - Oak
```

I would like to know how to group these under their parent type, sorting by that parent type and sorting the children. I assume the best thing to use would be an NSMutableDictionary to make them into keys and objects.

Here is what I tested so far but does not turn out how I want:

```
// Add to tree
if ([tree objectForKey:pathParent]) {
    NSMutableArray *temp = (NSMutableArray *)[tree objectForKey:pathParent];
    [temp addObject:name];
    [tree removeObjectForKey:pathParent];
    [tree setObject:temp forKey:pathParent];

} else {
    [tree setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:name] forKey:pathParent];
}//end
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Yes, you could use something like NSScanner or NSRange classes to get the different parts of your string. Then if the first part is equal to one of the keys in your dictionary, put the second part in as a value.

Comment: Are you just asking if it's possible, or for some guidance on how to do it? An NSDictionary doesn't have an inherent order to its keys, so "Fruit", "Tool",etc won't be sorted. The object for each key could be an NSArray (e.g. ["Apple","Banana","Orange"]) and those could be sorted as an array.

Comment: I need guidance on how to do it.

Comment: Ha, not homework, I am giving a very general example for a more complex problem I need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to perform an alphabetical sort on the original list

```
Tool: Saw
Fruit: Apple
Fruit: Orange
Tree: Maple
Fruit: Banana
Tree: Oak
Tool: Hammer
Tree: Cedar
```

To get:

```
Fruit: Apple
Fruit: Banana
Fruit: Orange
Tool: Hammer 
Tool: Saw
Tree: Cedar
Tree: Maple
Tree: Oak
```

From there you can easily iterate over the array and format it. Look at the first part of the first string and print it then newline the second part. Look at the second string if its first part differs you have a new parent so print like you did the first otherwise just print the second part of the string. Continue in this fashion.

You could also store the elements in a tree so instead of having a list of strings that are in the "parent:node" format you would have a tree of nodes with children. This would give you the ability to have child nodes with children and so forth.

The first option works, but the tree data structure is the more robust option that would be easier to expand upon.

Let me know if those don't make sense and I'll update to clarify.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.  I am wanting to store it in a tree structure.  Are you suggesting using an NSDictionary of keys (fruit, tool, tree), and the object for each of those is an NSArray?

Comment: I was suggesting you write your own tree data structure, kinda like a binary tree but with up to n child nodes for every node. In your current example you would need a generic root node to connect all the "categories" making your tree very wide, but that isn't necessarily a bad thing. An NSDictionary of NSArrays would work for the example given but if you ever wanted to add another level of depth it would be very difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

[NVM, I see you got it working already! Cool.]

Something roughly like this should work, you'll need to season and debug to taste of course. But this is the general idea...

```
- (NSDictionary*)categoriesAndSortedItemsFromItems:(NSArray*)source {

    //Given NSArray *source with the lines you described...

    NSMutableDictionary *categoriesAndItems = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];

    // Plug the items into the correct arrays by category
    for (NSString *line in source) {

        NSArray *components = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@": "];
        NSString *category = [components objectAtIndex:0]; //e.g. "tree"
        NSString *item = [components objectAtIndex:1]; //e.g. "oak"

        NSMutableArray *itemsForCategory = [self arrayInDict:categoriesAndItems forKey:category];

        [itemsForCategory addObject:item];
    }

    // Now run through and sort each array if you want...
    NSMutableDictionary *categoriesAndSortedItems = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];

    [categoriesAndItems enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

        NSArray *sorted = [(NSArray*)obj sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
        [categoriesAndSortedItems setObject:sorted forKey:key];
    }];

    return categoriesAndSortedItems;

}

 - (NSMutableArray*)arrayInDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict forKey:(NSString*)key {

        NSMutableArray *array = [dict objectForKey:key];

        if (!array)  {

            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

            [dict setObject:array forKey:key];

            [array release];
        }

        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got working inside my for loop:

```
if (pathParent != nil) {
    if ([tree objectForKey:pathParent]) {
        [[tree objectForKey:pathParent] addObject:name];
    } else {
        [tree setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:name] forKey:pathParent];
    }//end
}//end
```

Comment: Just a small thing, if the array exists, you can just [temp addObject:name]. There is no need to remove that array from the dictionary and then add that same array back again. So you can omit those two lines.